# como me puedo redireccionar en la misma pagina en angular

Tags: html, angular

hola tengo la siguiente fracción de código:

```
    <div class="content-img" id="img2">
    <a href="#img1" class="icon-left-open"></a>
    <img src="../../../../../assets/images/2.jpg">
    <a href="#img3" class="icon-right-open"></a> 
  </div>

  <div class="content-img" id="img3">
    <a href="#img2" class="icon-left-open"></a>
    <img src="../../../../../assets/images/3.jpg">
    <a href="#img1" class="icon-right-open"></a>
  </div>
```

estoy trabajando en angular, en una subcarpeta que cree, lo que necesito es que se redireccione a la misma pagina, pero me redirecciona a home. le agradecería el que me colabora. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera de resolver esto es asi:

Senalas el elemento con `#elemento` en el `html`

```
<p #elemento>Scroll aqui</p>
```

Y en tu component.ts creas esta operacion:

```
  scroll(el:HTMLElement){
    el.scrollIntoView()
  }
```

Y llamas al evento `click` con la referencia y la funcion `scroll` de esta manera en la etiqueta deseada:

```html
(click)='scroll(elemento)'
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://angular-ivy-ca6zpk.stackblitz.io).

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, tengo una duda en la etiqueda a tengo que poner (click)='scroll(elemento)'     por ejemplo   
    <div class="content-img" id="img1">
        <a  (click)='scroll(img3)' class="icon-left-open"></a>
        <img src="../../../../../assets/images/1.jpg">
        <a  (click)='scroll(img2)' class="icon-right-open"></a>
    </div>

Comment: No entiendo el comentario. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar más información

Comment: no estoy seguro donde poner el evento click si en el html o dentro de la etiqueta a o donde ya que agrege el scroll en el .ts, ya que el ejemplo no lo pude habrir, la verdad soy nuevo en esto y estoy perdido

Comment: En la etiqueta que quieras que ejecute la acción. Puede ser un link o un button